# rendering views inside view while processing ajax form in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

while processing a form with an Ajax call to one of my controller function then it will show a notification inside a div i need to display this notification message which already included with the design with special css format .. 
i though it can be done through rendering the notifications view which i split it from the main design 
i tried to do like this ..

```
public function add ()
    {
        $data = array();
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->model->insert();
                    $this->load->view('dashboard/notification', $data);
            exit;
        }
        $this->load->view('dashboard/categories', $data, FALSE);
    }
```

but sadly it didn't work and nothing appear .. 
when i printed a simple message to show if everything working normally it shows up the message and print it normally ..

```
public function add ()
        {
            $data = array();
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->model->insert();
               echo 'message';
                exit;
            }
            $this->load->view('dashboard/categories', $data, FALSE);
        }
```

and this is the jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $("#addCatgory").validate({
         rules: {
                categoryname: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 5
                },
                categoryslug: {
                   required: true,
                   minlength: 5
                },
                categorytype: {
                   required: true,
                   min : 1
                }
          },        
          messages:{
               categoryname : 'Please enter your name',
               categoryslug : 'Please enter a valid email',
               categorytype : 'Please enter a valid type'
          },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
               $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                   type: "POST", 
                   async: false,  
                   data: $("#addCatgory").serialize(),
                   success: function(data){
                       $('#result').html(data);
                   },
                   error: function(){alert('error');}
                });
              }                                       
          });
   });
```

Comment: I suspect there is an error in dashboard/notification.php that is preventing it from returning anything.

Comment: it just a pure html file what error should it have ?

Comment: Without seeing it I have no way of knowing, but you need to learn why it doesn't return any data when you tried Ahmed's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify this part by setting TRUE as third parameter so HTML is printed back to your Ajax response

```
public function add ()
    {
        $data = array();
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->model->insert();
                    echo $this->load->view('dashboard/notification', $data, TRUE);
            exit;
        }
        $this->load->view('dashboard/categories', $data, FALSE);
    }
```

Comment: it didn't work also i don't know if its right to echo rendering of the view